# sending email [html] via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email

I'm new in javascript. I would like to ask if its possible to retrieve values from html input to javascript? i have this email form here where the user inputs its information and etc. I wonder how would this work?

NOTE: I know how to do it on php. but I'm not planning doing it on php. the email form that im currently working on is a widget. I don't like user will be directed to another page and etc.

Here's my email form [HTML]

```
<div class="box box-info">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    <h3 class="box-title">Quick Email</h3>
                                    <!-- tools box -->
                                    <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                    </div><!-- /. tools -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <form action="#" method="post">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailto" placeholder="Email to:"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Message" style="width: 100%; height: 125px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-footer clearfix">
                                    <button class="pull-right btn btn-default" id="sendEmail">Send <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></button>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Is your question can JavaScript send email, or is it how do you retrieve user input values?

Comment: You would use Ajax to send the data to a (php) script that sent the email, a process that would be invisible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Only option in html is the [mailto protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
mailto:email@example.com?subject=xxx&body=xxx
```

This will open op the users mail client, with pre filled values for subject and body.

As you can see this is not always the optimal solution, instead you can use server side scripts to send the mail. As you mention you dont want the page to change etc..

Look at [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) which is a method to send data from the client -> server without a full page refresh.

For ease you maybe want to look at [jQuery's implementation of ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: As everyone probably knows,  doing it with  mailto: opens the email address up to spammers, they have crawlers that look for these.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sendMail(){
  
  var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
  var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
  
  open('mailto:email@email.com?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + message);
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"/><br/>
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="sendMail()" value="Send Message"/>
```